# Detecting the angle of an objected detected by YOLO

Tags: python, image-processing, tracking, detection, angle

I detected the above syringe correctly using YOLO. Now I would like to know how to measure the approximate angle at which the syringe is given? Any thoughts? I am required to correctly predict "with margin of error" the angle between the syringe and the surface. I was thinking to detect the deviation angle between the baseline which is the image lower edge of the syringe. I am not sure if my assumption is correct. Also, is there a way to draw a line that cuts in the middle of syringe based on its orientation?

[Syringe Training Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62xMO.png)

Comment: Consider adding some information about what you have tried so far and and some example code showing how you have extracted the syringe.

Comment: Please show the results you have so far and how you got them. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell.. I update an image of the output & better explained my thoughts

Comment: Surely it is just `atan2(bounding box height/bounding box width)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also train the network to predict the angle in addition to the bbox if you have data annotated with angle.
If you do so I would advise predicting 2 values which are cosine and sine of the angle instead of directly the angle to avoid the wrap around at -pi/pi.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.. Unfortunately I don't have the! I am asked to predict the angle to evaluate performance of trainees. Can you please elaborate a bit more? I wanna know what you mean by "Avoid the wrap around at -ip/ip"?

Comment: The "wrap around" issue is that the -pi angle is the same as the pi angle and this could disturb the proper training of the network. You don't have this issue with sine and cosine representation of the angle.